# How to add compile option for ModelSim using VUnit?

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, vunit

Using ModelSim and [VUnit](https://vunit.github.io/) I try to compile some [UVVM](https://github.com/UVVM/UVVM_All), but this gives some warnings like:

> ** Warning: C:\work\Qtec\SVN_sim\Design\uvvm\uvvm_util\src\methods_pkg.vhd(1159): (vcom-1346) Default expression of interface object is not globally static.

So I would like to suppress these warnings, so I tried updating the VUnit "run.py" file with `add_compile_option` based on [VUnit Python Interface](https://vunit.github.io/python_interface.html):

```
uvvm_util = prj.add_library('uvvm_util')
uvvm_util.add_source_files(join(root, '../../uvvm/uvvm_util/src/*.vhd'))
uvvm_util.add_compile_option('modelsim.vcom_flags', ['-suppress 1346'])
```

But when compiling, I then get the error:

> Compiling ....\uvvm\uvvm_util\src\types_pkg.vhd into uvvm_util ...
>
> ** Error (suppressible): (vcom-1902) Option "-suppress 1346" is either unknown, requires an argument, or was given with a bad argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could edit the `suppress` entry in the `modelsim.ini` file. [source](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/134097-modelsim-command-reference-manual-v10-3a)

It could be a python/TCL error with spaces. [See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497668/problem-starting-program-vcom-with-multiple-arguments-in-tcl).
So the space between `-suppress` and `1346` is not properly forwarded.

The VUnit [ui.py](https://github.com/VUnit/vunit/blob/master/vunit/ui.py) shows

> `modelsim.vcom_flags`
>      Extra arguments passed to ModelSim `vcom` command.
>      **Must be a list of strings.**

I cannot test it, but this case the line should possibly be:

```
uvvm_util.add_compile_option('modelsim.vcom_flags', ['-suppress', '1346'])
```

edit: after some reading... To me the difference between `add_compile_option` and `set_compile_option` is not clear. Maybe you could try the other?

Comment: Splitting the string in the list to `['-suppress', '1346']` made it work.  Actually pretty odd, since I had previously successfully used `prj.set_sim_option('modelsim.vsim_flags', ['-suppress 8684'])`, so it appears that `add_compile_option` is more picky.  About `set` vs. `add`, then `set` clear any previous options, where as `add` appends to any previous options.

Comment: @EquipDev thanks for pointing me to VUnit. I did not know it yet, but I'm really interested.